# What is the best budget NVidia video card for i5 6600k?

Tags: graphics-cards

My new PC which was bought for gaming has the following parameters:

- CPU - Intel Core i5 6600k
- DRAM - DDR4-2133 8Gb
- MB - Asrock z170 pro4s
- SSD Sandisk 128Gb SATA 6Gb/s
- Single monitor

And I have Asus HD 7750 video card which is the weakest part. I need a video card better than this with price lower than $250.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Under $250 GPU options as of 6/14/16*

**If you are willing to wait**:

- Nvidia - GTX 1060 - You mentioned this specifically, so I'm placing
  it ahead of the 480X. This card is rumored to be priced between
  $200-250 and is expected between late Summer and Fall of this year.
  It should perform slightly over the 480X, though everything is
  speculation at this point.
- AMD - Radeon 480X - These will be released at the end of the month
  with a $199 price point. The performance should place this card in
  line with a GTX 970 / Radeon 390X. There are numerous benchmarks
  available supposedly showing this card, but many of these are purely
  synthetic such as 3DMark, so it is possible that they may perform
  slightly better or worse in actual games.

**If you need to buy a card today**:

- Your best option for performance per/$ right now will be used from
  eBay - there you can pickup a GTX 970 for under $200 without much
  hunting. I have had good luck with hardware on eBay. It may seem like
  a gamble but, from experience, I can tell you that eBay will forcibly
  refund your money from the seller in the event that they are
  dishonest and try to pass off dead hardware (this has happened to me
  once).
- Alternatively, you can check out some of the larger hardware forums
  and look at their Buy/Sell sections (examples: HardOCP forums,
  Overclock.net, many others). These sites typically require the seller
  to be a user with X posts/rep, meaning that the GPUs for sale are as
  described and shipped/packaged safely.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the Nvidia Geforce GTX 960. It is around $250 and is one of the best budget cards. It has either 2GB or 4GB of VRAM, if you are just running 1 or 2 1080p monitors are do not do anything VRAM intensive (e.g. run song really VRAM demanding games, render videos in 4K, run virtual machines), then the 2GB is enough. If you do run more than 2 1080p monitors or 4K monitors, then the 4GB VRAM option is better.

Comment: You can probably wait for a price drop of the GTX 970 due to the arrival of the new GTX 1070 and GTX 1080. Or to even wait for the arrival of the GTX 1060 (I assume this one should be 2 times better than GTX 960 for the same price).

Answer (score 1):

I have the i5 6600K as well in my Gaming Rig.

I went for a GTX 970, and paid 285 Euro in December 2015. However, I've seen this card last week for 212 Euro.

So right now, I definitely would wait, namely for the new [AMD 480](http://www.cnet.com/news/nvidia-gtx-1080-vs-1070-vs-amd-rx480-gpu-price-availability/). Wait until some benchmarks have been made, and until the consensus says that it is a solid card. They announced it in the US for 200$, and what they claim seems seriously promising.